# Oracle extract json fields using regular expression with oracle regexp_substr

Tags: json, database, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I'm using Oracle query with **regular expression** and oracle **regexp_substr** to extract json fields from **JSON** string.

whene I try to get the value of code key it working well and its value, but whene i try to get the value of results key it return null.

I'm using this query:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('{"code":"001","message":"success","transactionId":437,"results":{"name":"osama"}}','"results":\s*("(\w| )*")', 1, level), '"results":\s*"((\w| )*)"', '\1', 1, 1) results
 from dual
connect by regexp_substr('{"code":"001","message":"success","transactionId":437,"results":{"name":"osama"}}', '"results":\s*("(\w| )*")', 1, level) is not null;
```

What is wrong in this query? 
Thanks

Comment: That is because \w only matches alphanumeric characters. The string you are trying to match inside results is - `{"name":"osama"}` which has curly braces,double quotes, and colon. Are you on oracle 12c?

Comment: Thanks @ruudvan ,No I'm not using oracle 12c , can you help me with correct expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing for the different data format.  This results in `{"name":"osama"}` which I hope is what you want:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('{"code":"001","message":"success","transactionId":437,"results":{"name":"osama"}}','"results":\s*{"(.*| )*"\}', 1, level), '"results":\s*(\{.*\})', '\1', 1, 1) results
 from dual
connect by regexp_substr('{"code":"001","message":"success","transactionId":437,"results":{"name":"osama"}}', '"results":\{(.*)"\}', 1, level) is not null;
```

Comment: Thank You so much for saving my time , it's working well