# sql query with multiple partial match condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

i have a table column looks like below. 
what is the sql query statement i can use to have multiple partial match conditions?

search by ID or Name

if search abc then list the row A1 , row A2

if search test then list the row A1 , row A2, row 3

if search ghj then list the row A2

i was trying this but nothing return:

```
 SELECT * FROM table where colB LIKE '"ID":"%abc%"'
```

[image: table column]

updating data in text

```
{"ItemId":"123","IDs":[{"ID":"abc","CodingSystem":"cs1"}],"Name":"test itemgh"}

{"ItemId":"123","IDs":[{"ID":"ghj","CodingSystem":"cs1"}],"Name":"test abc"}

{"ItemId":"123","IDs":[{"ID":"defg","CodingSystem":"cs1"}],"Name":"test 111"}
```

Comment: Please tag with your database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle).  You will probably have to use JSON functions to handle your requirement.

Comment: Postgres or Microsoft SQL Server? The syntax for JSON functions will be very different

Answer (score 1):

## JSON parsing

### Oracle

Looked into the JSON parsing capabilities of Oracle and I managed to make running a query like this:

```
select * from table t where json_exists(t.colB, '$.IDs[?(@.ID=="abc")]') or json_exists(t.colB, '$.IDs?(@.name=="abc"')
```

And inside the same JSON query expression:

```
select * from table t where json_exists(t.colB, '$.IDs[?(@.ID=="abc" || @.name=="abc")]')
```

The call of function `json_exists()` is the key to this.
The first parameter can be a `VARCHAR2`, and I also tried with a `BLOB` containing text, and it works.
The second parameter is the path to your json object attribute that needs to be tested, with the condition.

I wrote two `OR`ed conditions for the `ID` and for the `Name`, but maybe there is a better JSON query expression you can use to include them both.

More information about `json_exists()` function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/condition-JSON_EXISTS.html#GUID-D60A7E52-8819-4D33-AEDB-223AB7BDE60A).

### Postgres

There is a JSON datatype in Postgres that supports parsing in queries.
So, if your `colB` column is declared as JSON you can do something like this:

```
select * from table where colB->>'Name' LIKE '%abc%';
```

And in order to have available the array elements of the IDs array, you should use the function `json_array_elements()`.

```
select * from table, json_array_elements(colB->'IDs') e where colB->>'Name' LIKE '%abc%' or e->>'ID' = 'abc';
```

Check an example I created for you [here](https://rextester.com/EYAHLF4618).

[Here](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/) is an online tool for online testing your JSON queries.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) question in SO.

### MSSQL Server 2017

I made a couple of tests also with MS SQL Server, and I managed to create an example searching for partial matching in the name field.

```
select * from table where JSON_VALUE(colB,'$.Name') LIKE '%abc%';
```

And finally I arrived to a working query that does partial match to the `Name` field and full match to the `ID` field like this:

```
select * from table t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(colB, '$.IDs') WITH (
        ID VARCHAR(10),
        CodingSystem VARCHAR(10)
    ) e
where JSON_VALUE(t.colB,'$.Name') LIKE '%abc%'
or e.ID = 'abc';
```

The problem is that we need to open the `IDs` array, and make something like a table from it, that can be queried also by accessing its columns.

The example I created is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90cc9/51).

## LIKE text query

Your tries are good but you misplace the `%` symbols. They have to be first and last in your given string:

If you want the ID to be the given value:

```
SELECT * FROM table where colB LIKE '%"ID":"abc"%'
```

If the given value can be anywhere, then don't put the `"ID"` part:

```
SELECT * FROM table where colB LIKE '%abc%'
```

If the given value can be only on the ID or Name field then:

```
SELECT * FROM table where colB LIKE '%"ID":"abc"%' OR colB LIKE '%"Name":"abc"%'
```

And because you are giving hard-coded identifiers of fields (eg ID and Name) that can be in variable case:

```
SELECT * FROM table where lower(colB) LIKE '%"id":"abc"%' OR lower(colB) LIKE '%"name":"abc"%'
```

Assuming that the number of spaces do not vary between the `:` character and the value or the name of the properties.

For partial matching you can use more `%` in between like `'%"name":"%abc%"%'`:

```
SELECT * FROM table where lower(colB) LIKE '%"id":"abc"%' OR lower(colB) LIKE '%"name":"%abc%"%'
```

## Regular Expressions

A different option would be to test with regular expressions.
Consider checking this: [Oracle extract json fields using regular expression with oracle regexp_substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479090/oracle-extract-json-fields-using-regular-expression-with-oracle-regexp-substr)

Comment: . your first solution return no record. second solution isn't the one i wanted as i want to search at the ID or Name only

Comment: @user12158726 Is it possible to copy and paste the example data in the question? Currently there is an image with the test data.

Comment: @user12158726: you should treat that string as a proper JSON value and use the JSON functions your database supports. Using `LIKE` for this, isn't a good idea

Comment: added data in text @sanastasiadis

Comment: SELECT * FROM table where colB LIKE '%"ID":"abc"%'  this one does not work. no record return. i guess i have to learn about jsonvalue statement

Comment: @user12158726 Check the latest update of my answer. I updated with Postgres information. Check the example I created for you also.

Comment: @user12158726: can you please finally tell us which DBMS product are you really using?

Comment: @user12158726 I updated my answer with updated info about MSSQL Server.

Comment: i have tried For partial matching , if actual result, name is not match but id is match ,then the query give me 0 record which is not right.

Comment: @user12158726 The idea is the same. If you want partial matching for ID also, then you put `LIKE` operator and you can use `%abc%` with wildcards.

Comment: i guess you guys misunderstand the requirement. i know LIKE operator, just when it needs to have 2 combination of fields condition, it does not works.

Comment: @user12158726 Then it sounds like you have to change the operator 'OR' with an 'AND'.